# Troubles with everything that is not a homepage of wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am working on the site: http://cancerhope.com/

If you go to the home page it works but if you click on any of the links it doesn't. It did work before but I had a nameserver issue that I resolved last Friday. I have tried various permalink settings (default, postname, date, etc.) It is currently set to postname but none of the pages work and I am not getting any errors in my console. I have tried turning off the plugins to no avail.

Here is a page that shows up blank: http://cancerhope.com/consultation/

I have tried deactivating all the plugins and changing the theme to a standard WP theme. I have deleted the htaccess file and reset the permalinks to default as well as postname and other settings. I even deleted the htaccess file between these changes.

Current htaccess code is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Nothing seems to work.

Strange thing is that the blog page works:

http://cancerhope.com/blog-2/

The actual article that we have there works to:

http://cancerhope.com/2015/08/welcome-to-cancerhope/

Any suggestions?

Comment: try deleting .htaccess file. that might help or maybe you have some other code in your theme that is causing errors.

Comment: Yes i think too that the problem is in your .htaccess file… If you have written  custom redirections rules, don't delete it, instead update your answer with this .htaccess code

Comment: Nope, deleted the htaccess file and only got a 404 error. Changed it back to default permalinks and deleted it again and got a blank page.

Comment: I have also tried changing to the TwentyFifteen theme and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your server has `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: No, but the site was working fine before. We had some trouble with a DNS entry that took it down and it is now back. Hosting is with Network Solutions, where could I check that?